# Is there a combinatorial way to calculate the probability of a run in this scenario?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Say I have a vector (list) $V$ consisting of $O$ ones and $Z$ zeroes, e.g., ${1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0}$ has $O$ of 3 and $Z$ of 5.

I take $K$ random permutations of $Z$ and then sum the results, e.g, say $K$ were 2, and the two random permutations of the above $Z$ were ${1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1}$ and ${0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0}$, giving a sum of ${1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, 1}$.

I'm interesting in calculating the probability, given $O, Z$, and $K$, of a run of $R$ or more zeros in the resulting sum.

Right now, I'm just using a simulation, but I'm wondering if there is a direct combinatorial way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Is there any particular range of values of parameters that you are interested in? For example, $O<<Z$ or $O>>Z$, $K$, $R$ large or small?

Comment: @A.S. : Yes, as a matter of fact in my current needs, $O<<Z$ (as in 2-4 and 200-300 respectively), $K$ is between 50 and 60, and $R$ between 10 and 20. I am after an *exact* solution is possible, or if not a very accurate estimator, else I might as well just simulate it.

Comment: and do you want necessarily probability of a run of at least $R$ zeros or are you trying to approximate some other metric/express some other more general notion? Basically what is the real problem for which you came up with this model.

Comment: @A.S.: I am only interested in the probability of runs of at least $R$ zeros. The real problem has to do with a random allocation of resources into resource slots where the slots represent a temporal sequence.

Comment: Are all parameters in question fixed quantities or themselves distributed somehow and you are interested in average (max/min) over those distributions?

Comment: For any given case of interest, they are all fixed for that case. I am only after probability for some fixed set of parameters for a given case - I'll know them beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

Average ones per bit:
$$r=\frac {OK}N\in[0.33|0.67|1.20]$$

Probability that a given bit is $0$ after $K$ permutations are added up:

$$p_1(N)=(1-\frac O N)^K\lessapprox e^{-OK/(N-O/2)}\lessapprox e^{-r}\in[0.30|0.51|0.72]$$

Let $X_i$ be an indicator variable of the event that bits from $i$ to $i+R-1$ are all $0$ (run of length $R$) (with cancellation for $O\le R$ as the case for given parameter values):

$$p_R(N)=P(X_i=1)=\prod_{i=0}^{R-1}p_1(N-i)=\left(\prod_{i=0}^{R-1}\frac {N-O-i}{N-i}\right)^K=\left(\prod_{i=0}^{O-1}\frac{N-R-i}{N-i}\right)^K\lessapprox\left(\frac{N-R-(O-1)/2}{N-(O-1)/2}\right)^{OK}\lessapprox e^{-OKR/(N-(O+R-1)/2)}\lessapprox e^{-rR}\in[3.47\cdot 10^{-11}|4.11\cdot 10^{-5}|3.74\cdot 10^{-2}] \tag 1$$

Let $W=\sum_{i=1}^{N-R+1} X_i$ be the total number of such runs. Then $$E(W)=(N-R+1)p_R(N)\in[6.94\cdot 10^{-9}|1.03\cdot 10^{-2}|11.2]REVISE$$

If $E(W)$ is not too large, we can get a great approximation by Poisson. A run of length $R$ will be followed by an average of $\frac {p_1(N-R)}{1-p_1(N-R)}$ more runs for a total of $\frac 1 {1-p_1(N-R)}$ runs clumped together. Hence density of isolated clumps of length at least $R$ is $$\lambda\approx p_R(N)(1-p_1(N-R))$$ which implies that

$$P(W=0)\approx \exp(-\lambda (N-R+1))\approx $$

---

If we are interested in approximating all of $W$, not just $P(W\ge 1)$, we can use [Stein's method](http://www.math.illinois.edu/~psdey/414CourseNotes.pdf) (specifically p.15) 
Collection ${X_i}$ is positively associated and $$E(X_iX_j)\approx p^Rp^{\min\{|i-j|,R\}}$$
Approximate $W$ by $\bar W=Pois(\lambda)$ where $\lambda=Np^R$. Then $$|P(W\ge 1)-(1-e^{-Np^R})|\le d_{TV}(W,\bar W)\le\min\{1,1/\lambda\}(var(W)-\lambda+2Np^{2R})=\min\{1,\lambda\}(2\frac {p-p^R}{1-p}-(2R-3)p^R)$$
If $\lambda$ or $p$ is are small, the approximation is good in absolute terms. If $p$ is small, it's good in relative terms as well.